# Spark streams: enrich stream with reference data

Tags: streaming, apache-spark

I have spark streaming set up so that it reads from a socket, does some enrichment of the data before publishing it on a rabbit queue.
The enrichment looks up information from a Map that was instantiated by reading a regular text file (Source.fromFile...) before setting up the streaming context.

I have a feeling that this is not really the way it should be done. On the other hand, when using a StreamingContext, I can only read from streams, not from static files as I would be able to do with a SparkContext.

I could try to allow multiple contexts but I'm not sure if this is the right way either.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making the assumption that the map being used for enrichment is fairly small to be held in memory, a recommended way to use that data in a Spark job is through *Broadcast variables*. The content of such variable will be sent once to each executor, avoiding in that way overhead of serializing datasets captured in a closure.

Broadcast variables are wrappers instantiated in the driver and the data is 'unwrapped' using the `broadcastVar.value` method in a closure.

This would be an example of how to use *broadcast variables* with a DStream:

```scala
// could replace with Source.from File as well. This is just more practical
val data = sc.textFile("loopup.txt").map(toKeyValue).collectAsMap() 
// declare the broadcast variable
val bcastData = sc.broadcast(data)

... initialize streams ...

socketDStream.map{ elem => 
    // doing every step here explicitly for illustrative purposes. Usually, one would typically just chain these calls
    // get the map within the broadcast wrapper
    val lookupMap = bcastData.value
    // use the map to lookup some data
    val lookupValue = lookupMap.getOrElse(elem, "not found")
    // create the desired result
    (elem, lookupValue)
}
socketDStream.saveTo...
```

Comment: Thank you much. I'm quite new to Scala and Spark, so forgive my ignorance. Two questions: 1. In what way is sc.textFile(...) more practical than Source.fromFile(...) ?  2. sc.TextFile assumes SparkContext, so how do I get a StreamingContext from a SparkContext ?

Comment: @KoenDejonghe (1) practical just b/c I get an RDD and can apply the same transformation model. `Source.fromFile` will be fine as well. (2) how are you creating the StreamingContext?  if you have a StreamingCtx, you can do `streamingContext.sparkContext` but I usually create a `streamingContext` from an existing `sparkContext` like: `val ssc = StreamingContext(sparkContext, interval)` -- groeten vanuit Anterpen :-)

Comment: I'm learning by the minute here. StreamingContext(sparkContext, interval). They don't teach you that in 'Learning Spark'. Thanks and groeten uit Duffel.

Answer (score 4):

If your file is small and not on a distributed file system, `Source.fromFile` is fine (whatever gets the job done).

If you want to read files via the SparkContext, you can still access it via `streamingContext.sparkContext` and combine it with the DStream in `transform` or `foreachRDD`.

Comment: streamingContext.sparkContext: beautiful. I didn't know this. Thank you.